# special character in header of a column in mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, character

```
string q="SELECT CONCAT(" + table_users + ".f_name," + table_users + ".l_name) AS Username, (" + table_ship + ".name_it-ITA) AS Lang FROM...";
```

Hello, I have trouble with this special charachter "-".  In PHP I resolve it with backticks, but in C# I cannot resolve it.
Tried with [] and backticks, also with '', but no success.
It would be easier to rename column header name "name_it-ITA", but I cannot do that.
Do you have any idea?

BR

Comment: You should be able to resolve with backticks just as easily in C#, there must be some other issue with your query (like perhaps allowing dynamic table names).

Comment: it's mysql. doesn't matter what language you're talking to mysql with, you're still just sending sql to mysql, and have to write it in mysql's required form. `[]` are not quote/escape characters in mysql.

Comment: ``foo.`name_it-ITA`) AS Lang``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you can use always bacticks these are not related to C#

```
"SELECT CONCAT(" + table_users + ".f_name," + table_users + ".l_name) AS Username, 
 (" + table_ship + ".`name_it-ITA`) AS Lang FROM..."
```

In mysql all column and table name can wrapped with backtics